# Возможно ли удалить объект, на который ссылаются одновременно несколько ссылок? - C#

Tags: c#, объекты, ссылки, null

```
class A
{   
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A superA = new A();
        A[] arr = new A[10000];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = superA;
        }
    }
}
```

Можно ли как-то удалить объект `superA`, чтобы все ссылки из массива стали автоматически указывать на `null`?

Comment: Сделали `superA` Равным `null` И все ссылки будут очищены сборщиком мусора.

Comment: Позвольте спросить, зачем вам это нужно? C# -- это не С/С++.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов нет же, установив null, вы только 1 ссылку очистите, остальные 10000 будут все еще ссылаться

Comment: @simplygood понял, извиняюсь за ложные указания.

Comment: Чтобы объект пропал необходимо удалить все ссылки на него. Если занулить superA  = null все элементы массива будут продолжать ссылаться на этот объект. Чтобы уничтожить все ссылки нужно также очистить твой массив занулив его или удалить все элементы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой функциональности C# не предоставляет.

Попробуйте в данной ситуации

```
Array.Clear(arr, 0, arr.length);
```